# Return of Date or Calendar Field

Tags: java, date, gwt

Netbeans is complaining about this code, which appears on the [IDEA Code Inspections List](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp).

```
 public Date getStartDate()
 {
    return theStartDate;
 }
```

IDEA site says:

> This inspection reports any attempt to return a java.lang.Date or
>   java.lang.Calendar field from a method. Since Date or Calendar are
>   often treated as immutable values but are actually mutable, this
>   construct may result in an object having its state modified
>   unexpectedly. While occasionally useful for performance reasons, this
>   construct is inherently bug-prone.

How else would I return a `Date`?

Comment: `return new Date(theStartDate.getTime());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should most likely return a copy of the value in question, rather than your current object, to avoid unintentional modifications

the simplest is probably
`return new Date(theStartDate.getTime());`

This is because java.util.Date is a mutable object, and you want to avoid problems from your caller mistakenly or maliciously doing something like:

```
yourObject.getStartDate().setTime(0);
```

If you make the change above, a statement like the one above becomes harmless.

Why a copy constructor and not the clone mehod?  See here:  [java.util.Date clone or copy to not expose internal reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082553/java-util-date-clone-or-copy-to-not-expose-internal-reference)

Note that this will have the performance penalty of creating a new object on every call to the method, so use with caution.

Comment: One should move from `Date` and `Calendar` to classes from the newer `java.time` package.

Answer (score 2):

`return new Date(theStartDate.getTime());`

Answer (score 2):

IDEA is simply saying that Date objects are often used as immutable objects. The reasonable solution is to return a new Date object, with theStartDate.getTime() in it's constructor. This maintains the immutability of the original Date object :)

Answer (score 1):

You could return the date as an immutable long (`Date.getTime()`) . This insures that the date is not changed by the caller.

Another option would be to get the date as a long and return a new date `return new Date(dateAsLong)`. This would protect the original date while still returning a Date object.

Comment: A `long` for a date? Yuck.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline The only non-deprecated constructor for java date (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) takes long as the input parameter for "milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"

Comment: So call it for me. (Point of pedantry: The no-args constructor is also non-deprecated.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I was looking at the wrong date (sql.date vs util.date http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Long is a valid way to represent time but if used people should be aware that it does not have the protections or context that a date object would.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could return the `long` milliseconds value that the `Date` represents:

```
public long getStartDateMilliseconds()
{
    return theStartDate.getTime();
}
```

Returning the `long` value still allows you to return the `Date` information, and prevents the caller from modifying a returned `Date`.  Then the caller could re-construct the `Date`:

```
Date theDate = new Date(myObject.getStartDateMilliseconds());
```

That should pass the IntelliJ inspection.