# Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object

Tags: java

I have the following code in my dto class.

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = billDate;
}
```

And I get an error in sonar stated as such and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object
```

The class is a dto and the method is automatically created setter method. What am I doing wrong here. if anyone could explain. it would be a great help.

Comment: You could trying using `this.billDate = new Date(billDate.getTime());` instead...

Comment: Is dto; data transfer object? Undefined acronyms can only lead to confusion

Comment: Sorry it's not a dto.. it's an entity class. sorry!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

### `Date` is mutable

Using that setter, someone can modify the date instance from outside **unintentionally**

Consider this

```
class MyClass {

   private Date billDate;


   public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
      this.billDate = billDate;
   }

}
```

now some one can set it

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();

Date dateToBeSet = new Date();
m.setBillDate(dateToBeSet); //The actual dateToBeSet is set to m

dateToBeSet.setYear(...); 
//^^^^^^^^ Un-intentional modification to dateToBeSet, will also modify the m's billDate
```

To avoid this, you may want to **Deep-copy** before setting

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = new Date(billDate.getTime());
}
```

Comment: how can this be achieved if my instance variable was an Array of Dates ? can i use Arrays.copyOf ?

Comment: @yathirigan yes. Basically you need to do deep copy, so that outside modification doesn't affect the object held within this instance

Comment: thank you.. am confused looking at few articles that state that Arrays.copyOf does not do a deep copy. am doing some reading around it.

Comment: also is clone useful, eg. billDate.clone()

Comment: What if we write `this.billDate = billDate.clone();` ? It is also the same

Comment: are we saying, sonar will actually look at this deep copy code and understand?

Answer (score 51):

I wonder why none of the solutions takes null into consideration. A general, null-safe solution should look like this:

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = billDate != null ? new Date(billDate.getTime()) : null;
}
```

Comment: maybe because you should avoid using null values as it is considered by many as antipattern

Comment: @Zavael The whole point of this is "you don't know what people outside the class are going to do with the values". You can't expect everyone to never pass you a null value.

Comment: @Demonblack I agree you can't excpect everyone to never pass a null, but you can "punish" them with appropriate exception :) if the caller does not have a value to set, he shouldn't call the method at all

Comment: @Zavael Or, we can accept the Date to be a null instead of just punish them. Just like this answer.

Comment: @Nier yes we can, but I prefer to avoid it where I can

Comment: @Zavael Most of time throw exception is a good choice. But recently I'm dealing with JPA with a nullable Date field in get / set functions. I need to consider the null case because it's legal to set / get a null Date.

Comment: Is there any open source utility method with this code?
I wonder if apache commons lacks it.

Comment: I added a utility method to do this `public static Date dateCopy(Date d) { return d != null ? new Date(d.getTime()) : null; }` to avoid having null checks sprinkled everywhere in code.

Answer (score 6):

A counter argument can be, why one would one *unintentionally* modify the date? If client sets the value and then modifies it, then our code should reflect it, isn't it? If not then is it not confusing?

I prefer to just ignore this FindBugs warning.

In case if you want to do that, just add following Maven dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- Findbugs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and then these annotations at class or member field level in your POJO:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = { "EI_EXPOSE_REP", "EI_EXPOSE_REP2" }, justification = "I prefer to suppress these FindBugs warnings")
```

Cheers

Akshay

Answer (score 3):

### `Date` is mutable

and you are *not creating* a *copy of* `Date` that came in to you are parameter. So if the client code will change the value of the `Date` object, it will affect your class too.

Solution is to create a copy of `Date`

```
public setBillDate(Date billDate){
   this.billDate = new Date(billDate.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a clone as well. Don't forget null check.

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = billDate == null ? null : billDate.clone();
}
```

Comment: This might be an option for `java.util.Date` (for Java 7+, see the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/a/18954948/1098673), see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7082614/1098673 But it is not the right solution in general, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: billDate.clone() returns an Object, you will have to cast (which I think is bad) it to a Date Object to set the field.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the existing answers, I propose a new version based on `Optional` class from Java 8.

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = Optional
            .ofNullable(billDate)
            .map(Date::getTime)
            .map(Date::new)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Date is not immutable, i.e. your billDate can be changed after it has been set on your DTO object. Or, in code:

```
Date billDate = new Date();
dto.setBillDate(billDate);
billDate.setYear(1990);
// now, dto.getBillDate().getYear() == 1990
```

You can make your setter more secure:

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = (Date)billDate.clone();
}
```

Comment: The default `clone()` will create shallow copy, so it might not fix the problem

Comment: In Oracle's JDK 7 it's overwritten to create a deep copy. But you're right, the API doc only says: 'Return a copy of this object.' - that does not fully explain the type of copy it creates.

Answer (score 1):

Top answer number 37 is not the correct answer : nobody cares about NullPointerExceptions???

You should try this instead :

```
public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
    this.billDate = billDate == null ? billDate : new Date(billDate.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Null is already mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21113988/923794).