# How is "May expose internal representation" a malicous vulnerability?

Tags: java, security, spotbugs

I am utilizing spotbugs to help review an oracle adf application for errors and vulnerabilities prior to deployment.  Two of the malicious code vulnerabilities warnings spotbugs finds are:

- "*classname* may expose internal representation by returning *fieldname*"
- "*classname* may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into *fieldname*".

I understand that a caller could alter the object undesirably in some way and that could be prevented by returning or setting a copy of the object.  That situation and resolutions are explained in other questions like [Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954873/malicious-code-vulnerability-may-expose-internal-representation-by-incorporati)

Are there other specific security risks of exposing internal representation that would need to be addressed if copying the object is undesirable?

Comment: As far as I can see they are pretty much the same thing: the first is about exposing a mutable value and the second about accepting and storing one. Both cause fundamentally the same issues (of outside code being able to manipulate the internal state outside of  the intended methods for that). It's possible that `fieldname` *doesn't* actually reference a mutable class, though. Spotbugs has had bugs in that area and flagged classes as mutable too aggressively sometimes.

Comment: I agree they are essentially the same things and SpotBugs correctly identified that they were externally mutable.  Since it is flagged by SpotBugs as a malicious vulnerability and not a practice one, I am trying to determine if there are other risks associated with exposing the external representation.  Unless I am seriously misunderstanding something, things like jsf or framework component bindings need to able to access an object externally and using copies of the object instead could/would interfere with functionality.