# How to add items to the list?

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

I have problems in add instances to list in RHS of rule.

There're two classes shown as below:

```
class Person {
    private java.lang.Integer age;
    private java.lang.String name;
}

class A {
    private java.util.List<Person> persons;
    private java.util.List<Person> selectedPersons;
}
```

In the following rule, I want to put person with age larger than 30 into selectedPersons.

```
rule "test"
when 
    $a:A()
    $p : Person(age > 30) from $a.persons
then
    $a.getSelectedPersons().add($p);
end
```

It works in eclipse, with Drools plugin; **but it doesn't after deploying to KIE server. What I get is the instance reference only.** Any ideas?

Also, I wonder why KIE server throw **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** Exception when I add following constructor to Person class, while workbench can build and deploy the rule successfully:

```
public Person(Person p)
{
    this.name = p.name;
    this.age = p.age;
}
```

Comment: why not write a function to add into list, and call that function in drools?

Comment: What do you mean by "what I get is the instance reference only"? - No stack trace and full error message for the NSME?

Comment: @piyushj, could you please give an example of the function, and how to call it in drools?

Comment: @laune While I said "instance reference only", I mean in the drools result,  there's only something like `<selectedPersons>
    <Person reference="../../selectedPersons/Person"/>
</selectedPersons>`, but no `name` or `age`

Comment: @laune Also, what does NSME mean here?

Comment: NSME is `NoSuchMethodError ` @dehiker

Answer (score 1):

The class should look like this:

```
class A {
    private java.util.List<Person> persons;
    private java.util.List<Person> selectedPersons;

    //First create getter, setter for the lists.
    void addToList(Person item)
    {
        selectedPersons.add(item);
    }
}
```

And the rule should look like this:

```
rule "test"
when 
    $a:A()
    $p : Person(age > 30) from $a.persons
then
    $a.addToList($p);
end
```

Comment: While validating, I got __The method put(Person) is undefined for the type List<Person>__. Any ideas?

Comment: edited the answer, `put` is not a valid command for list, its `add`

Comment: Hmm, I got the same result as that of `$a.getSelectedPersons().add($p);`, the reference only.

Comment: If you are adding a list item, from another list......... you will get reference only, so please be specific which value you need to deduce

Comment: Yes, I need to add an item from one list to another, so I try `add(new Person($p))` too, which sometimes gives me NSME, sometimes not, even I add the constructor mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. "What I get is the instance reference only"

I should **add constructor mentioned in the question**. BTW, if there's a Date attribute in Person class, it should be copied or cloned, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082553/java-util-date-clone-or-copy-to-not-expose-internal-reference).

2. "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Exception when I add following constructor to Person class"

Hmm, after **deleting the container and create it again**, exception disappeared. I don't know if it's a problem of drools (Version 6.2), or a problem of process of setting up drools.