# clone() non final classes

Tags: java, clone

As per Josh Bloch's Effective java :-

> do not use the clone method to make a defensive copy of a parameter
>   whose type is subclassable by untrusted parties.

Now taking a expert from his book only:-

```
public final class Period {
private final Date start;
private final Date end;

/**
 * @param  start the beginning of the period
 * @param  end the end of the period; must not precede start
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if start is after end
 * @throws NullPointerException if start or end is null
 */
public Period(Date start, Date end) {
    if (start.compareTo(end) > 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            start + " after " + end);
    this.start = start;
    this.end   = end;
}

public Date start() {
    return start;
}
public Date end() {
    return end;
}

...  // Remainder omitted
```

}

I do not get what wrong would happen if I modify a accesor method to return a copy of date object using clone function instead of copy using constructor like this :-

```
public Date start() {
    return start.clone();
}
```

instead of

```
public Date start() {
       return new Date(start.getTime());
}
```

How possibly can a instance of malicious subclass be returned?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082553/java-util-date-clone-or-copy-to-not-expose-internal-reference

Comment: As Date is not Final class so clone() is not guaranteed to return defensive  copy of the object.

Answer (score 3):

Take the `java.util.Date` class which provides a defensive copy in its `clone()` method but which is also not final.
Suppose I subclass `Date` and I override the`clone()` method.
Now, at runtime, if I receive an instance of this subclass, `clone()` of Date  is not used anylonger. So, I am not sure that the implementation of the child class makes still a defensive copy as the original.

This :

```
public Date start() {
    return start.clone();
}
```

will not be a defensive copy if a subclass overrides `clone()` like that :

```
@Override 
public Object clone() {
    return this; 
}
```

Comment: You mean to say :-  Period p = new Period(new MaliciousDate(), new MaliciousDate()); would potentially cause harm? MaliciousDate extends Date and override clone().

Comment: Yes if you call the clone() method on these parameters and the MaliciousDate implementation of clone() is not a defensive copy. In this case, you will provide the same instance to your client. And that, even if the clone() method of Date makes a defensive copy. Because at the runtime, it is the method of the effective instance which is called.

Answer (score 0):

Instance of malicious subclass be returned for the accessor method. Quoting from the same chapter -

> In the accessors, unlike the constructor, it would be permissible to
>   use the clone method to make the defensive copies. This is so because
>   we know that class of `Period`'s internal `Date` objects is
>   `java.util.Date`, and not some potentially untrusted subclass.

Expanding a bit on

> do not use the clone method to make a defensive copy of a parameter
>   whose type is subclassable by untrusted parties.

Since `Date` is not final, it can be subclassed to change its behavior so the clone method of `Date` could very well return an instance of a malicious subclass.

Example

```
public class TestNonFinalCloneIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NonFinalDate start = new NonFinalDate();
        NonFinalDate end = new NonFinalDate();
        Period p = new Period(start, end);

        // We are completely obvious to the fact that copies of our data
        // exists in another malicious class
        System.out.println("Secretly copied data - " + NonFinalDate.MaliciousDate.getListOfInstances());
    }
}

final class Period {
    private final NonFinalDate start;
    private final NonFinalDate end;

    public Period(NonFinalDate start, NonFinalDate end){
        NonFinalDate s = start.clone();
        NonFinalDate e = end.clone();
        if (s.compareTo(e) > 0){
            throw new IllegalStateException(start + " after " + end);
        }
        this.start = s;
        this.end = e;
    }
}

class NonFinalDate extends Date{
    @Override
    public NonFinalDate clone(){
        // NonFinalDate returning a malicious subclass (subclassing possible only because NonFinalDate is not final)
        return new MaliciousDate(this);
    }
    static class MaliciousDate extends NonFinalDate {
        private static List<NonFinalDate> listOfInstances = new ArrayList<>();

        public MaliciousDate(NonFinalDate date){
            // Secretly making copies of the data
            listOfInstances.add(date);
        }

        public static List<NonFinalDate> getListOfInstances() {
            return listOfInstances;
        }
    }
}
```