# Mutable items in Immutable

Tags: java, immutability, immutables-library

When we create immutable classes using the [Immutable objects](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html) library, how can we handle mutable members (e.g. [j.u.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html))?

NOTE: this is **not** about the java Date class and totally related to the **Immutable Objects** java library which will generate some code!

Example:

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface MyImmutableClass {
    Date creationDateTime();
}
```

Is there a way to override the getter, so that it returns a copy?

```
public Date creationDateTime() {
    return new Date(creationDateTime.getTime());
}
```

Comment: You could use an [immutable date class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), or, yes, by all means have your getter return a copy. `return new Date(creationDateTime.getTime());`

Comment: I cannot use java8 features and it could also affect other classes - not just Date.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082553/java-util-date-clone-or-copy-to-not-expose-internal-reference

Comment: @khelwood that is not helpful, since it is not at all about the Immutable Objects library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my question in the [Immutables issue tracker](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/557) I learned that the cleanest way to handle mutable objects is to use a [custom encoding annotation](http://immutables.github.io/encoding.html).

I've created a little open source project [tmtron-immutables encoding](https://gitlab.com/tmtron-immutables/encoding#use-custom-type-encoding-annotation) to create such an annotation for the `java.util.Date` class. This should be a good starting point for anyone who wants to create a custom encoding.

Then you can directly use your mutable class (e.g. `java.util.Date`) as attribute and still get the same immutability guarantee as for immutable attributes (like String, long, etc.)

```
@Value.Immutable
@DateEncodingEnabled
public interface ValueObject {
    Date creationDate();
}
```

The `@DateEncodingEnabled` annotation will make sure that only the immutable long value of the Date object is stored in the `ImmutableValueObject` class.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to override the getter, so that it returns a copy?

Pretty much like you've written it there:

```
public Date creationDateTime() {
    return new Date(creationDateTime.getTime());
}
```

(like [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) pointed out in the comments above).

However, if you want to avoid accidental mutation of `creationDateTime` inside your class, consider just storing the millis as a `final long`:

```
private final creationDateTimeMillis;

public Date creationDateTime() {
    return new Date(creationDateTimeMillis);
}
```

Whereas you can call `Date.setTime()` even if the `Date` is `final`, thus mutating the internal state, you can't reassign `creationDateTimeMillis`.

Comment: Well, I know that I must copy it somehow: The question is "How to tell the Immutables annotation processor to do this?"

Answer (score 1):

You can make the generated method `protected` and serve the field only from a cloning getter method:

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class WrapMutable {
    protected abstract Date timestamp();

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return new Date(timestamp().getTime());
    }
}
```

All usage of the field is then through its copy-getter, while the `timestamp()` method is only used to define the setter in the builder:

```
WrapMutable obj = ImmutableWrapMutable.builder().timestamp(new Date()).build();
System.out.println(obj.getTimestamp());
System.out.println(obj.timestamp()); // Error: timestamp() has protected access in WrapMutable
```

Comment: That's not really immutable. Just create a subclass of `WrapMutable`, and you can add a method to call `timestamp()` nefariously. You need to have the `timestamp` property store/return something immutable, like a `long`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: You have read the question in the context of the [Immutables framework](http://immutables.github.io/). Its purpose is not to guard against malicious developers, which can be very helpful during testing, but rather to deliver POJO instances on which you can make ton of assumptions, e.g. that collections are initialized, that fields are set, that Optionals are non-null etc. If you work with the framework it will eliminate a lot of boilerplate, and help you reduce the amount of defensive coding required.