# Is there a way to copy Date object into another date Object without using a reference?

Tags: java

I got a program that loads in raw data for charting and stores it in a class called `cRawGraph`..  It then formats this data and stores it in another class called `cFormatGraph`.  Is there a way to copy some of the date objects stored in `cRwGraph` to date objects stored in `cFormattedGraph` without using a reference? I looked at Oracle's documentation and did not see a constructor that would take in a date object or any methods data would accomplish this.

code snippet:

```
do{
        d=rawData.mDate[i].getDay();
        da=rawData.mDate[i];
        datept=i;
        do{
          vol+=rawData.mVol[i];
          pt+=rawData.mPt[i];
          c++;
          i++;
          if (i>=rawData.getSize())
              break;
          } while(d==rawData.mDate[i].getDay());

        // this IS NOT WORKING BECOUSE IT IS A REFRENCE AND RawData gets loaded with new dates,
        // Thus chnaging the value in mDate
        mDate[ii]=da;

      mVol[ii]=vol;
      mPt[ii]=pt/c;
      if (first)
      {
          smallest=biggest=pt/c;
          first=false;
      }
      else
      {
          double temp=pt/c;
          if (temp<smallest)
              smallest=temp;
          if (temp>biggest)
              biggest=temp;

      }
      ii++;
    } while(i<rawData.getSize());
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but you can use `b = new Date(a.getTime())` or `b = (Date) a.clone();` to clone a date object. BTW: your sample code does not actually contain the word "Date".

Comment: Why? What the problem with references? Why do you think you need new objects?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use getTime() and passing it into the Date(time) constructor. This is only required because Date is mutable.

```
Date original = new Date();
Date copy = new Date(original.getTime());
```

If you're using Java 8 try using the new [java.time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/) which uses [*immutable objects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So no need to copy/clone.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the answwer could you explain what immutable means?

Comment: Immutable means "cannot be changed" ie the date is fixed, this means you can safely pass objects around without worrying about client code changing the value, and also removes the need to clone objects.

Answer (score 9):

With **Java 8** you can use the following nullsafe code.

```
Optional.ofNullable(oldDate)
               .map(Date::getTime)
               .map(Date::new)
               .orElse(null)
```

Answer (score 3):

If possible, try switching to using Joda Time instead of the built in Date type.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

DateTime from Joda has a copy constructor, and is generally nicer to work with since DateTime is not mutable.

Otherwise you could try:

```
Date newDate = new Date(oldDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Doesn't Java 8 come with its own version of this JodaTime class so you no longer need to use joda?

Comment: @DanielKaplan No, Joda-Time is alive and well. While Joda-Time did indeed inspire the new java.time package built into Java 8, **java.time was re-architected**. So java.time is not a drop-in replacement for Joda-Time. Both Joda-Time and java.time have strengths and features the other lacks. Both are ongoing active projects. They are not mutually exclusive; you can use both in a project (just be careful with imports as a few class names are coincidentally the same). The [threaten-extra project](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) extends java.time to add more features.

Answer (score 0):

`Date d = (Date) oldDate.clone()`

get the reference of the object and cast it to date works too.