# Java deep copy difference between a String and Date object

Tags: java, cloneable, date

How to create a deep copy for a date object, for example birthDate of a student? how will copying a date object different from Name or age?

Here is an example for cloning I got from net.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Clone
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date d1 = new Date(90,10,5);
        Object d2=d1.clone();
        System.out.println("Original Date:" +d1.toString());
        System.out.println("Cloned Date:" +d2.toString());
    }
}
```

But is this a deep copying?

> OUTPUT  Original Date:Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 IST 2018  Cloned Date:Mon
>   Jan 05 00:00:00 IST 2018 –
>
> adding  additional Info...
>
> so how can I put the code inside my class  ?

```
// insideCloneable class
/overriding clone() method to create a deep copy of an object. 
protected Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{ 
        Employee employee = (Employee) super.clone();
        return employee;  
        }

//implementing  class - main method 
Employee employee1 = new Employee(01,"John","02-11-2017");
        Employee employee2 = null;
employee2=(Employee)employee1.clone();
```

Comment: That should be edited into the question, not posted as a comment.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) solve your problem? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332484/is-there-a-way-to-copy-date-object-into-another-date-object-without-using-a-refe)?

Comment: The `Date` class is long outmoded. I recommend you don’t use it anymore and instead look into [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date original = new Date();
Date copy = new Date(original.getTime());
```

[java 8+ new API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/)

[Original link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332484/is-there-a-way-to-copy-date-object-into-another-date-object-without-using-a-refe/28332590#28332590)

Comment: so how can I put the code inside my class  ?  (I have added this code to my  question...)



// insideCloneable class
/overriding clone() method to create a deep copy of an object. 
protected Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{ 
  Employee employee = (Employee) super.clone();
  return employee;  
  }

//implementing  class - main method 
Employee employee1 = new Employee(01,"John",dataentry);
  Employee employee2 = null;
employee2=(Employee)employee1.clone();

Comment: just override and put the code inside and return the copy object

Comment: Is it correct ?  sorry I am new to Java cloning.

public Date getbirthDate() {
        return new Date(original.getTime();
    }

Comment: It’s correct, @Vinod, but still uses the outdated `Date` class.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
newEmployee.setHiredDate( oldEmployee.getHiredDate() ) ;  // No need to copy/clone an immutable `LocalDate` object.
```

- Use `java.time.Instant` instead of `java.util.Date`.
- Use `java.time.LocalDate` for a date-only value.
- Being immutable, re-use the *java.time* object rather than copy/clone.

## java.time

The `Date` class is among the troublesome old date-time classes than are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

### `Instant`

The modern equivalent to `Date` is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC.
```

You can convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

### `LocalDate`

But you seem to be interested in a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone. If so, use `LocalDate`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "02-11-2017" , f ) ;
```

### Immutable object can be reused rather than cloned/copied

The java.time classes use [*immutable objects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). **So no need to copy or clone.** Simply assign the same object.

The new cloned `Employee` object gets a reference to the same `LocalDate` object held by the original `Employee` object.

### Strings

By the way, you can serialize the *java.time* objects to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings by calling `toString`.

```
String x = ld.toString() ;                        // Serialize object’s value as text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Instantiate by calling `parse`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-02-11" ) ;  // Parse text to instantiate object.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).